# How to disable rhythmbox port 3689?

Tags: rhythmbox, tcp-ip

I installed rhythmbox on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, since VLC several times hanged/crashed the GUI during video play.

But by suprise rhythmbox is listening on the public IP (not localhost) on port 3689, which is extremely dangerous!

How can I disable this listening on the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools/Plugins; uncheck "DAAP music sharing".

The actual text may differ (I only have a Dutch version) but the word to look out for is DAAP. If anyone has the proper texts please feel free to correct me.

As described [here](https://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/05/01/music-collection-sharing-with-rhythmbox/), your version/build of Rhythmbox supports DAAP sharing over port 3689.

I would not call that "extremely dangerous", but to each their own risk analysis.